# Is it possible for multiple Dynamic Link Libraries (DLL) to share Thread Local Storage from a Static Library (LIB)

Tags: c++, multithreading, dll, static-libraries, thread-local-storage

I have a game made up of many DLL files. Some of these DLLs link to the same static library (LIB).

So something like this:

```
Game.exe -> Root.dll -> Child.dll
               |            |
               |            '-> Common.lib (contains __declspec(thread))
               |
               '-> Common.lib (contains __declspec(thread))
```

Root.dll loads Child.dll which statically links Common.lib. Root also statically links Common.lib. Because Common is statically linked, it gets compiled directly into the loading dll (eg. Root and Child).

Common.lib contains a variable using Thread Local Storage (TLS).

```
__declspec(thread) static void* s_threadValues[PlatformThreadSlotsMax];
```

This results in some problematic behavior: Root.dll and Child.dll each contain a *different* instance of the TLS data (s_threadValues). Even on the same thread, if Root.dll calls a function defined in Common.lib, the value of s_threadValues will be different from its value if that same function is called from Child.dll.

Since both DLL are accessing this TLS from the same thread, I would expect the TLS to be shared, but it is not.

Now, if I change Common.lib to a dynamically link (eg. Common.dll) this issue does **not** occur anymore: s_threadValues is the same for both Root.dll and Child.dll.

Is this expected behavior? Is there anyway to have the TLS shared defined in the static lib shared between dynamic libs using it?

Comment: Singletons are useful here, though if you want your class to remain static that doesn't work so well (You'd have to expose a setter for your singleton - it's hacky but it works). I'm hope there's a better solution, though.

Comment: AFAIK, It is expected behavior: "Global" variables are global only to a Module (in the Windows sense). To share one between modules, you have to either store it in a single module and let others call it, or find another kind of storage (personnally I use a File Mapping with a processID-based name)

Comment: @Warty Are you saying, that rather than having s_threadValues as a global, have it as a member of a Singleton (and not a TLS value)? In doing that, would it not end up being shared between threads (which it was trying to avoid in the first place)?

Comment: @Medinoc And a DLL would be considered a "single module", where as a static lib is not? Is the correct?

Comment: Static libraries are totally irrelevant. They do not exist in an executable program in any shape or form. They are just containers for object files. You might just as well never create any static library and use the object files directly.

Comment: `__declspec(thread)` does not cancel `static`. The variable is still local to the module.

Comment: @n.m. So are you saying this issue has nothing to do with TLS, but rather to do with the fact that the variable is declared as static? I am not totally clear on what you mean by Static libraries being irrelevant, in that if I use a DLL it shares the TLS and if I use a static lib is does not, so the static lib is at least affecting the outcome of the test.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Let me try again. There are **no** static libraries in executable code. They are just containers for object files, and object files are just containers for object code. The linker uses that object code to build modules (.dll and .exe files). You could just as well use object files directly, without ever creating static libraries, and build exactly the same modules. That's why the fact that you are using a static library is irrelevant. What's important is whether you have one copy of the variable in one module, or two such copies in two modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is entirely normal.  Each DLL has its own copy of the library code and data.  And its own thread-local state.

You can reason this out by assuming it would work the way you expected.  Then two DLLs could accidentally have their own thread-local variables shared between different DLLs.  Clearly that would be disastrous.  It can't work that way because there is no mechanism to share the TLS instance across modules.  The slot indices are intentionally kept private to the module, there's no mechanism to obtain the slot index of a __declspec(thread) variable.  Calling TlsAlloc() explicitly and sharing the index would be a workaround.  Don't go there.

Comment: In conclusion: leaving your "Common" library as its own, standalone DLL is the correct way to do it.  Sleep easy.

Answer (score 0):

While the author had accepted an answer by Hans Passant there is no obvious solution proposal in it. So this is what I've come up with. Not very elegant but slicing part of code into Common.dll may be even worse/ugly.

#### Common.h

```
class IContext
{
public:

    static thread_local IContext* g_ctx;

    virtual void setThreadContext() = 0;
    virtual void print(int) = 0;
};

// Example
class Log
{
public:

    // This code is static so will be compiled in each module. Thus
    // gets access to different "g_ctx" per thread per module
    // With TlsAlloc() approach we need another static variable for index, 
    // while thread_local will get it from _tls_index
    // (see \Visual Studio\VC\crt\src\vcruntime\tlssup.cpp)
    //
    // mov r9d, dword ptr [_tls_index (07FEE05E1D50h)]
    // mov rax, qword ptr gs:[58h]
    // mov rsi, qword ptr [rax+r9*8]  // g_ctx address is now in rsi

    static void print(int x)
    {
        IContext::g_ctx->print(x);
    }
};
```

#### ChildDLL.cpp

```
#include "Common.h"

thread_local IContext* IContext::g_ctx = nullptr;

DLLEXPORT void setDllThreadContext(IContext* ctx)
{
    // sets g_ctx in this module for current thread
    IContext::g_ctx = ctx;
}

DLLEXPORT void runTask(IContext* ctx)
{
    createThread(&someThreadFunc, ctx);
}

void someThreadFunc(IContext* ctx)
{
    // will call setDllThreadContext() above
    ctx->setThreadContext();
    ...
}
```

#### main.cpp (root exe or dll)

```
#include "Common.h"

thread_local IContext* IContext::g_ctx = nullptr;

// pointers to setDllThreadContext from each loaded DLL (engine plugins use case)
/*static*/ std::vector<void(*)(IContext*)> GameEngine::modules;

class Context : public IContext
{
public:

    void print(int) override {...}

    void setThreadContext() override
    {
        g_ctx = this; // sets context for this module (where setThreadContext is compiled)

        for(auto setDllContext : GameEngine::modules)
        {
            setDllContext(this); // sets context for module where setDllContext was compiled
        }
    }
};
```